# joy_node how to publish to cmd_vel topic?

Tags: ros, joy-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, Ubuntu 20.04 with Noetic installed on robot. Have a motor driver working and can drive the bot with:

"rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py cmd_vel=:/hoverboard_velocity_controller/cmd_vel"

Then installed joy_node, and tested input from game controller. (don't seem to have proportional values from joy sticks - a drama for later) but for now I just need it to publish to /hoverboard_velocity_controller/cmd_vel.

How do I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404006/joy_node-how-to-publish-to-cmd_vel-topic?/) by [TK hobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/76726/tk-hobby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a node called `teleop_twist_joy` which listens to `joy` messages and produces `Twist` messages. Works with a bunch of different joysticks. That joystick problem seems problematic though - maybe fix it before testing with live motors.

---

Originally posted by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) with karma: 501 on 2022-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TK hobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/76726/tk-hobby/) on 2022-07-21**:
OK, so start joy_node- witch reads joystick, then start teleop_twist_joy- witch listen to joy..stick and then add: cmd_vel:=/hoverboard....../cmd_vel. - witch should then publish Twist messages to robot just like : teleop_twist_keyboard ?

I will give a it a go soon. got caught with my pants down.... installed something (with out making a backup) and broke my serial coms to robot. I have borrowed a xbox 360 wired controller to test and see if issue is with my controller or somewhere else.

Thanks for now

**Comment by [TK hobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/76726/tk-hobby/) on 2022-07-25**:
spot on! thanks that solved it. ...run joy_node. another terminal run teleop_twist_joy and add cmd:=*what ever you want to pipe it to*  If you want to change the parametors then add _paramettor after dont forget the dash

**Comment by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on 2022-07-25**:
Awesome! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.